# Command line parameter for WinSCP to edit a remote file

Tags: batch-file, ssh, winscp

Is there a way to create a batch file where we can edit a remote file using WinSCP editor?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `/edit` command-line parameter:

```
winscp.exe sftp://user@example.com/ /edit /home/user/file.txt
```

Reference: [WinSCP Command-line Options](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline).